# AWSeducate credentials are not accepted for Elastic Beanstalk ebcli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

When I log into my awseducate account and I click on **Account Details** I get my credentials. 
[See the credentials generated by the account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbM7r.png)

I successfully used these credentials with my S3 buckets to upload and download files. But when I try to use these credentials with elastic beanstalk service - ebcli (**eb init** command), I get the message **ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.**

```
F:\cloud-developer-master\course-02\project\image-filter-starter-code>eb init

Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
4) eu-west-1 : EU (Ireland)
...
(default is 3): 1
You have not yet set up your credentials or your credentials are incorrect
You must provide your credentials.
(aws-access-id): ASIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
(aws-secret-key): hVCExxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Any clues why these are not accepted?

NB: I can't create new crenditials with a new user because this operation is not allowed with this AWS Student account.
I tried refereshing the page to get new credentials, still no success.

I tried creating the **.aws/credentials** file and copied and pasted those credentials, still not accepted:

```
F:\cloud-developer-master\course-02\project\image-filter-starter-code>eb init

Select a default region
1) us-east-1 : US East (N. Virginia)
2) us-west-1 : US West (N. California)
3) us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
...
(default is 3): 1
ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.
ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.
You have not yet set up your credentials or your credentials are incorrect
You must provide your credentials.
(aws-access-id): ASIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
(aws-secret-key): 1Ssxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a guy that goes by the pseudo **Gambit-**, I found a solution to the problem ([details here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html)).
You have to create two files in the folder: C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\.aws

**config**

```
[default] 
region = us-east-1 # replace this with your region (don't select it in the CLI) 
output = json
```

**credentials**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SECRET_KEY
aws_session_token=REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_TOKEN
```

A little explanation: 
When you select the region within the cmd, eb-cli will automatically update the **config** file by generating and storing a new profile named **[eb cli]** which will be populated with the information your select within the cmd. However, I did put the profile **[default]** in the file **credentials** which are two different profiles. Therefore, the authentication failed.

Also, thanks John Rotenstein for your help

Answer (score 1):

AWS Educate is providing you with *temporary* credentials that expire after a period. They are generated via the AWS Security Token Service (STS).

Temporary credentials consist of:

- Access Key
- Secret Key
- Session Token

The `eb init` script you are showing is only asking for the first two items, but not the **Session Token**. Without the session token, the credentials are invalid.

It *might* be possible to overcome with this method:

- Run `aws configure`, which will ask you for the credentials and then store them in `~.aws/credentials` (including the security token)
- Run `eb init`, which should use the credentials from that file

Worst case, use an alternative profile via `aws configure --profile foo` and then `eb init --profile foo`.

Comment: How do I introduce the session token? It is not required by aws configure, on AWS Access Key ID, AWS Secret Access Key, Default region name, and 
Default output format are required. BTW, I tried creating .aws/credentials file, still it did not work (see updated post).

Comment: Ah! You're right, sorry. You can enter the Access Key and Secret Key via `aws configure`, but then you will need to edit the `~.aws/credentials` file to add another line with `aws_security_token=TOKEN-HERE`

Comment: I tried **aws_session_token=TOKEN-HERE** and also **aws_security_token=TOKEN-HERE**. None of these options solved the problem.